# Contiguous memory zone with with Numpy C API?

Tags: python, c, memory-management, numpy

I try to change my old C API numpy code to the 'new' API. I used to hack some internal stuff in Numpy (yes it's bad...) and I wonder now how to change it.

Let's take an example: I have *ocount* numpy arrays with data allocated elsewhere than numpy, the data pointer of the *PyArray_Object* is set with the malloc'd zone.
Now I select one of these array to be the memory base for all of them, then I **realloc** each data pointer to make sure the *ocount* of them have a **contiguous** zone.
The code is now 'rejected' by the new API, how can I do that without hacking into the *PyArray_Object*?

```
first=(PyArrayObject*)context->ctg_obj[0];
psize=PyArray_NBYTES(first);
for (j=1;j<ocount;j++)
{
  current=(PyArrayObject*)context->ctg_obj[j];
  tsize=PyArray_NBYTES(current);
  psize+=tsize;
  ((PyArrayObject*)first)->data=realloc(PyArray_DATA(first),psize);        /* *** how to do that with the API ? */
  memcpy(PyArray_DATA(first)+psize-tsize,PyArray_DATA(current),tsize);
  free(PyArray_DATA(current));
  ((PyArrayObject*)current)->data=PyArray_DATA(first)+psize-tsize;
}
```

I use that trick to make sure that separate numpy each representing a coordinate of a vector can be gather in a single array.
I've had a look at *NPyArray_resize* but it requires a **own_data** flag which I do not have...
Any hint, remark?

Comment: Ok, I've used `PyDataMem_RENEW` to reallocate through the API